# PHP: Initializing constants from a property file

Tags: php, constants

Let me put the requirement to satisfy first

A PHP gateway, and a set of request handlers which uses many constants which currently i am defining in a `constants.php` with `define('conts','value');`

I can define this constants in a property file like

```
const1 =val1
const2 = val2
const3 = val3
```

in some external file say `gateway.properties` and load it to `define()` at runtime. Can this be a one-time action, so that as many threads created by the php can access this constant further, with out reloading it again?

I dont know if this is really possible, i want an expert advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this by stuffing the resulting object in [memcached](http://memcached.org/).

There is obviously some overhead with this.  You will need to weigh whether or not it makes sense for your situation.  For 3 variables, it won't make sense at all.  For 300,000, maybe it will.  Test it and see.

Comment: i'm already using memcache for other purposes. this way is good, just wanted to confirm whether i can use it as a constant like CONST_1 instead of $memcache->get(CONST_1)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP it is preferred to use .ini files and use

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php
or php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php if you have read the file to a string already.

You can use apc to cache it in memory with a fallback to reading a file if not already cached and then cache it.

```
<?php
$ini = apc_fetch('configuration');
if (!$ini) {
    $ini = file_get_contents('path/to/ini.ini');
    if ($ini) {
        apc_store('configuration',$ini);
    }
}
$config = parse_ini_string($ini);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read each line, parse out the = and define in a for loop.

Comment: I think he is trying to save the overhead of having to reload this file every time his application starts up.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to store your values in a `.ini` file, and then read the file in with `parse_ini_file()`.  The ini file would look like:

```
var1 = 'blah blah blah'
var2 = 'more blah'
```

PHP reads these files pretty quickly.  I suggest that, rather than turn all the values into constants, you store the associative array you get from the .ini file in a single global variable.  Let work, same visibility.

If you're really set on caching, you could use the APC cache.  It'll save a few miliseconds, but it won't make a difference unless you're talking about a pretty large set of values.  And you'll still have to call `define()` for each value, if you're going to insist on turning them all into constants.  Still much faster to save a single global associative array.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a static class which is globally easy to access.
You can create a class with only public static members and CLASS::init() calls an optional configuration file to replace the variables.
If the value is missing it will stay at it's default.
So you can access the configuration from everywhere using CLASS:$STATIC_VAR

The init function:

```
            $vars = parse_ini_file(dirname(__FILE__) .'/'. $filename,true,INI_SCANNER_TYPED);
            if ($vars)
            {
                foreach ($vars as $key => $val) 
                {
                        if (property_exists(get_called_class(),$key)) self::$$key=$val;
                }
            }
```